# Memory Error raised in python is not coherent with size of data fetched from MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, memory

I am trying to run the following script in python:

```
def pegaDia(dia):
sql = "SELECT * FROM registros WHERE data=%s ORDER BY idbilhete"
result = {}
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute(sql,(dia,))
a = cursor.fetchone()
while a is not None:
    if a['idbilhete'] not in result:
        result[a['idbilhete']] = list()
        result[a['idbilhete']].append((a['data'],a['hora'],a['linha']))
    else:
        result[a['idbilhete']].append((a['data'],a['hora'],a['linha']))
        print 'tamanho: '+str(sys.getsizeof(result))
        print sys.getsizeof(result[a['idbilhete']])
return result
porBilhete = pegaDia('20150209')
```

Basically, it just fetches `ints(a['data'],a['hora'],a['idbilhete'])`, all of which fit into python's 8-byte default allocation for integers, and strings with at most 5 characters `(a['linha'])`. For each separate value for `a['idbilhete']`, the code creates a list, into which it will append some `data(a['data],a['hora'] and a['linha'])` from every row where this particular `a['idbilhete']` appears. I don't know beforehand the number of ocurrences for each `'idbilhete'`, altough i suspect there to be at most a couple of thousand ocurrences for the most frequent one, and about 3 or 4 for the average case.

Upon trying to run this code with 64 bit python, I came across a `MemoryError`. Moreover, even with aprox. *4 GB* of free memory before the execution, the RAM from my laptop did get maxed out. How come is this so, given that the same query, when executed with `MySQL WorkBench`, returns `~314k rows`, which should fit confortably in my available space?

Comment: Whether 314k rows will fit in memory depends very much on the size of each row. but why on earth do you want to do this? Why don't you just iterate through the querysert directly without loading the data into a list?

Comment: e4c5, of course, there are tons of workarounds for this. The one you suggested, in particular, wouldn't really be useful to me, since what i would do with this fetch would be dependent of the iteration that i'm doing with another set of data. But, most of all, the fact of having no idea whatsoever why this is happening is what annoys me the most.

Comment: check what your heap limit is https://docs.python.org/2/library/resource.html#resource.getrlimit